# Navigate to Report in LWC without Apex

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, navigationmixin.navigate

I am redirecting to a report in LWC using navigationmixin. Is there a way where I can get the report id without calling apex method in LWC.

Below is the code.

```
viewReport( event ) { 
    this[ NavigationMixin.Navigate ]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: '00O1a0000038nL1EAI',
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        },
        state:{
            fv0 : this.recordId,
            fv6 : this.completeName,
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, you can save the id in a custom label and import it and use in your LWC. This wasy you can skip writing apex logic to find the report and get Id,but will have to configure this in every environment as a Post deployment step.

```
import reportId from "@salesforce/label/c.reportId";

connectedCallback() {
this.labelMessage = reportId;
console.log(labelMessage);}
```